# Test Unit with Angular service is not a function error

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

I'm using the tools (Karma, Jasmine) provided by Angular.

I just want to compare the received data and simulate an http get request.

But reusing my service, it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ApiConstants } from "../constantes/constantes";
import { User } from "../classes/user";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})

export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private cst: ApiConstants
  ) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.cst.apiUrl + "user/users");
  }
}
```

**user.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed, async, inject  } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { UserService } from "./user.service";

import { ApiConstants } from 'src/app/constantes/constantes';

import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('UserService', () => {

  let injector: TestBed;
  let userService: UserService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let cst: ApiConstants;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {provide : UserService}]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    userService = injector.get(ApiConstants, UserService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it("should be created", () => {
    expect(userService).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should return an Observable<User[]>", () => {
    let dummyUsers = [
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... }
    ];

    userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      expect(res.length).toBe(3);
      expect(res).toEqual(dummyUsers);
    });
    
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${cst.apiUrl}/user/users`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET'); 
    req.flush(dummyUsers);
  });
  
});
```

**Error :**
[Error return by Karma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zMP.png)

I tried a lot of tutorials, but I couldn't find anything.
If you have a tutorial with more explanation, don't hesitate to provide me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using Angular 9 because it's the first time I am seeing `getTestBed`.

Try changing according to the comments I have provided.

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed, async, inject  } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { UserService } from "./user.service";

import { ApiConstants } from 'src/app/constantes/constantes';

import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('UserService', () => {

  let injector: TestBed;
  let userService: UserService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let cst: ApiConstants;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
     // ** Change providers like so **
      providers: [
         UserService,
         ApiConstants,
      ]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    // ** Change your gets to this **
    cst = injector.get(ApiConstants);
    userService = injector.get(UserService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it("should be created", () => {
    expect(userService).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should return an Observable<User[]>", () => {
    let dummyUsers = [
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... }
    ];

    userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
      expect(res.length).toBe(3);
      expect(res).toEqual(dummyUsers);
    });
    
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${cst.apiUrl}/user/users`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET'); 
    req.flush(dummyUsers);
  });
  
});
```